# FileNotFound Exception trying simple Spring java application

Tags: java, spring

I have the following "Beans.xml"; it is in eclipse in a 'src' folder:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

        <bean id="user1" class="rc.User">
            <property name="name"    value="joe" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

I have the following java application:

```
package rc;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Asparagus 
{
    public static void main (String[] arguments)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = null;
        try
        {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        }
        catch (ExceptionInInitializerError eiie)
        {
            System.out.println(eiie);
        }
        System.out.println("hi");
        User u = context.getBean("user1", User.class);
        System.out.println("hi2");
        System.out.println(u);
    }
}
```

This is in an 'rc' package inside the 'src' folder in eclipse.  I have a User bean class, I guess I might as well include it:

```
package rc;

public class User 
{
    public User() {} 

    public String name;

    public String getName()                {return name;            }
    public void setName(String name)       {this.name = name;       }
}
```

And when I run this I get FileNotFoundException.  The only file I can think of it would be trying to find is my XML file, but I cannot figure out why it should have trouble.

I have looked using DOS at the directory structure, verifying that "Beans.xml" is in the root of the classpath of the application, both under src and bin.  I think that's verified by the fact that the Asparagus class (someone objected to it being called "Main") is found and starts running, which eclipse couldn't do if src/bin were not the classpath root.

I had included a mess of libraries recently on the advice of someone else, and this problem went away and I got another one that I found (in StackOverflow) to be caused by a jar being included in eclipse as a system library, so I took all the system libraries out except for the java runtime.

I would REALLY prefer not to solve this by adding a potful of libraries without knowing anything about what they are supposed to do.  Can someone explain what is happening here and why a suggested solution might fix things?

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Does `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Beans.xml")` return not `null` value when called in the beginning of `main`?

Comment: @Tomasz what a good check!  No, it returns an object.

Comment: I prefer to use `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` instead of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, than your Bean file doesn't have to be on the class-path, give it a simple relative path. do you need an example?

Comment: @CodeChimp I'll be happy to do that if you can tell me a good way.  It's 19 lines long, ending with the line that instantiates ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.  It goes through URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URL); could it be trying to load a required jar and not saying what it is ?

Comment: @Michael If I really cannot find anyone that can make THIS work, I'm willing to change methods.  But I'm really hoping to understand what's wrong with this, not just change it to something else.  I regard a file path as less flexible, and using it (assuming I can get IT to work) just means I don't learn what's wrong with this method.

Comment: It  should be `context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/Beans.xml");`

Comment: @CodeChimp:
rcAsparagus at localhost:1877
Thread[main](suspended(excpetion FileNotFoundException))
owns:Launcher$AppClassLoader (id=30)URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URL) line:644
URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$600(URLClassPath$JarLoader, URL) line: 540
URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run() line:607 [local variables unavailable]
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T> line: not available [native method]
URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen() line: 599 [local variables unavailable]
URLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(URL, URLStreamHandler, HashMap<String,Loader>) line: 583

Comment: @CC
URLClassPath$JarLoader$3.run() line: 810
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>
URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(String, boolean, Set<String>) line: 806
URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(String, boolean) line:765
URLClassPath.getResource(String, boolean) line: 169
URLClassLoader$1.run() line: 194
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>, AccessControlContext)
Launcher$AppClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String)
Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean)
Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean)

Comment: Use of either "/Beans.xml" or "./Beans.xml" as an argument to new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext() produces the same error.

Comment: what jars are you using for spring?

Comment: aop, asm, aspects, beans, context, context.support, core, expression, instrument, jdbc, orm, oxm, test, and transaction are all part of the build path in eclipse (all prefaced with org.springframework., all with 3.1.1.RELEASE appended).

Comment: @rcook I have tried out the code without changing and it works fine have you tried updating the spring version? Also try keeping the file in src/main/resources (if you are using maven and spring 3.1.2.RELEASE)

Comment: No maven, just as well.  I, also, have seen very similar code work, about to try to update jars in build path.  Don't see why I should move the xml; I'm trying to understand, not just get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be some as-yet-undetermined problem with the spring jars used in the project.

I had had a full set of spring jars - 8 or 10 of them - all named in the form org.springframework.-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar; these were placed as jars on the build path in Spring Tool Suite (aka eclipse).  Another programmer had a similarly simple project that was working which used jars in the form spring--3.1.2.RELEASE.jar, so I switched over to those.  Now the code works.

Thanks to all who offered help; I still don't know the difference between the two sets of jars or why the original error message was SO obscure (any code that throws a FileNotFoundException ought to be able to tell us something about which file).

Answer (score 0):

**ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:** You do not need to provide the full path but must be set `CLASSPATH` properly. 
If your code throw exception it means, container not found bean definition in classpath. Check classpath and try again.

If you use **FileSystemXmlApplicationContext** You need to provide the full path of the XML bean.

For Reference Check [Spring ApplicationContext Container](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_applicationcontext_container.htm)

Spring 3.1.x supports annotation, So i preferred the annotation `@Autowired` to initialize any bean.